# Claves foráneas en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un modelo llamado usuario con una clave primaria (id) y otro llamado articulo con una FK (id_autor).

En el modelo del Articulo tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function id_autor() {  
    return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id_autor');
}
```

Y en la vista intento obtener los datos del autor de ese artículo de la siguiente forma:

```
$autor = \App\Articulo::find('44')->id_autor; 
var_dump($autor)
```

Cuando hago eso solo recibo el id del usuario y no el modelo, si lo hago con paréntesis salta un error.

Comment: Buenas Alvaro, bienvenido. Respuestas a qué pregunta? Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b A que no funciona, solo me devuelve la id y quiero recibir todo el usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno, creo que es un poco confuso tu sistema de nombres y relaciones, yo creería que normalmente (aunque depende de como funcione tu aplicación) un autor **tiene muchos** artículos y un artículo **pertenece** a un autor.

Modelo articulo:

```
public function autor() {  
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id_autor');
}
```

Modelo autor:

```
public function articulos() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Articulo', 'id_autor');
}
```

A partir de esto no deberías tener mayor problema en obtener la relación como una propiedad mágica:

```
$autor = \App\Articulo::find(44)->autor;
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Ese era el problema, lo había codificado justo al revés. Muchísimas gracias a todos.

Comment: Si ahora, por ejemplo, quiero obtener una propiedad del autor. ¿Cómo lo hago?

Comment: No es más que una instancia como cualquier otra: `$autor->nombre`

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
$autor = \App\Articulo::where('id_autor', 44)->get();
```

Con `->id_autor;` lo que estás haciendo es pedir el id del objeto, si quieres el objeto entero hazlo de esa manera y en mi caso que uso eloquent embebido en CodeIgniter:

```
$autor = \App\Articulo::where('id_autor', 44)->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: Pero yo quiero obtener el objeto del usuario directamente a partir de un objeto Articulo. Te dejo el artículo de la documentación que he leído https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one